# How do I improve query speed on a paged grid with a large number of results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ibm-midrange, mvccontrib

I am querying data from our IBM i and displaying it in a grid. The purpose of displaying all records is for a couple reasons:

1. The existing software isn't used properly and people aren't closing out the items. (user/training issue yes, but see other items). So narrowing down the list to just open items isn't accurate.
2. It allows a user to query all history (this is property based and history can be important)

However, there currently is 28,000 items and will ever increase. Right now, I am using MvcContrib grid. Here is my code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int? page, int? filterPropertyUniqueKey, int? filterPermitNumber)
    {
        #region Filter and Sort
        var permits = buildingPermitRepository.GetOpenPermits();

        // Set default sort and apply filters
        if (filterPermitNumber.HasValue)
        {
            permits = permits.Where(w => w.PermitId == filterPermitNumber.Value);
        }

        // TODO add more filters

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(gridSortOptions.Column))
        {
            gridSortOptions.Column = "DateApplied";
            gridSortOptions.Direction = SortDirection.Descending;
        }

        var permitsPagedList = permits.OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction).AsPagination(page ?? 1, 20);
        #endregion

        var viewModel = new PermitIndexViewModel
        {
            BuildingPermits = permitsPagedList,
            GridSortOptions = gridSortOptions
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

What would you suggest I do differently to improve the display speed? At least for subsequent views.

Comment: [CodingHorror: The End of Pagination](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/the-end-of-pagination.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how AsPagination method works, but we use *Skip* and *Take* methods.
So after all filtering is done your code could look like this:

```
var permitsPagedList = permits.OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction).Skip(pageSize * (page -1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

This simple method returns only those rows which we actualy needs.